# How to combine multiple field in GraphQL Object

Tags: graphql

I am trying my first Graphql Schema design. Is it possible that single field inside object type refer to a complex object?

```
enum KeyPrefix {                                                                                      
    WS                                                                                 
    WK                                                                                   
    SI                                                                                          
    ENT                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                     

input generalKey {                                                                                    
    keyPrefix:KeyPrefix!                                                                              
    key:Int!                                                                                          
}                                                                                                     

type Item                                
{                                                                                                     
    pk: generalKey!                                                                                                                                                                              
    data: String!                                                                                     
    name: String!                                                                                     
}
```

It gives me error as below.
The type of Item.pk must be Output Type but got: generalKey!

Comment: You cannot use "input" as a type for other. Create "generalKey" as type.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is a keyword reserved for describing input to a GraphQL query. Your schema should look like this:

```
enum KeyPrefix {
  (your values)
}

type PrimaryKey {
  prefix: KeyPrefix!
  key: Int!
}

type Item {
  pk: PrimaryKey!
  data: String!
  name: String!
}
```

When you define a `Query` in your GraphQL schema, you will want to use an `input`, like so:

```
input PrimaryKeyInput {
  prefix: KeyPrefix!
  key: Int!
}

type Query {
  getItemByPrimaryKey(input: PrimaryKeyInput!): Item
}
```

This will allow a client to ask for an `Item` using the same fields you have on `PrimaryKey`.